# Backbone: subviews, default "div" wrapper, and delegated events

Tags: events, backbone.js, subviews

We have two Backbone Views: a parent view (PersonView) and its subview (LocationView).
Their templates, in Mustache notation, are the next:

```
PersonView template:
    <h2>{{fullName}}</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>Address:</h3>
        {{{location}}}
    </div>

LocationView template:
    <hr />
    <dl>
        <dt>City:</dt>
        <dd>{{city}}</dd>
        <dt>Place:</dt>
        <dd>{{place}}</dd>
    </dl>
```

NOTE that these templates does NOT have a parent element; so, Backbone will asignate them
the "div" element by default in the "el" property.

In PersonView's "render" method, How can we add the LocationView's rendered HTML into
"PersonView.el" WITHOUT loossing LocationView's events and WITHOUT ADDING the deafult wrapping
"div" element of "LocationView.el"?

We have tried many ways, and if we remove de subview's "el" property, we always loose the
events (in the subviews), but if we keep that "el", then we have problems if we want to 
associate it with jQuery events :-(

Anybody has any solution about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered setting `tagname: 'dl'` in LocationView, then remove the <dl> tag from the template? Then Backbone would create a <dl> element instead of the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment...

LocationView:

```
var LocationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'dl'
});
```

LocationView template:

```
<dt>City:</dt>
<dd>{{city}}</dd>
<dt>Place:</dt>
<dd>{{place}}</dd>
```

PersonView template:

```
<h2>{{fullName}}</h2>
<div>
    <h3>Address:</h3>
    <hr />
    {{{location}}}
</div>
```

Now, in LocationView instances, `this.el` will be a `<dl>` instead of a `<div>`.

Comment: Hello, Paul. Thanks, but, you are overlooked the "<hr />" inside the template. These two templates have no root element: no "div", no "dl", nothing.

Comment: A Backbone view always has a root element, you will not get around that.  So, it seems like a good solution for the root element of the LocationView to be a `dl` element, then move the `hr` into the PersonView template, I guess.  Or, you keep the `div` as the root element and change your css accordingly.